# C# DevExpress - EndCallback Event Not Raised

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, devexpress, devextreme

I have a callback panel with a method who builds a XtraReport in Runtime and after that, convert the file to base64. All Right with this, but after that, EndCallback event not raised and aspxloading panel stay and don't closed.

My method:

`if (base64.Length > 0) {`

```
callback.JSProperties["cp_close"] = "registerOk"; callback.JSProperties["cp_msg"] = "Report Successfull"; }
```

JS EndCallback:

`<dx:ASPxCallbackPanel ID="callback" runat="server" ClientInstanceName="callback" Width="100%" OnCallback="callback_Callback"> <SettingsLoadingPanel Enabled="False" /> <ClientSideEvents BeginCallback="function(s, e) { loading.Show(); }" EndCallback="function(s, e) { loading.Hide(); if(s.cp_close=='registerOk') { swal('',s.cp_msg,'success'); } }"/> </dx:ASPxCallbackPanel ID>` 
Thanks!

I try with Edge, Chrome, Brave, Opera and mozilla. I expect once the report is created and base64 it's ok, the endcallback event raised and display the message.